# GraphQL with React Router Relay: Expected type Int, found String for numeric route

Tags: react-router, graphql, relay, react-router-relay

I have the following Router and routes using the [react-router-relay](https://github.com/relay-tools/react-router-relay) package

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router
        history={browserHistory}
        render={applyRouterMiddleware(useRelay)}
        environment={Relay.Store}
    >
            <Route
                path="/user/:userId"
                component={User}
                queries={StoreQueries}
            />   
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My StoreType from GraphQL looks like the following, with the user field accepting an id argument representing a non-null integer:

```
let StoreType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Store',
    fields: () => ({
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {
                id: {
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt)
                }
            },
            resolve: (root, args) => db.user.findById(args.id)
        },
    })
})
```

My Relay container for the `user/:userId` route:

```
import React from 'react';
import Relay from 'react-relay'


class User extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div>
            User goes here!
        </div>;
    }
}

User = Relay.createContainer(User, {
    initialVariables: {
        userId: null,
    },

    fragments: {
        store: () => Relay.QL`
            fragment on Store {
                user(id: $userId) {
                    name
                }
            }
        `
    }
});

export default User;
```

When I visit /user/1 in the browser, react-router-relay treats `:userId` as a string from the route instead of an integer, and GraphQL returns the JSON-encoded error message `"Argument \"id\" has invalid value \"1\".\nExpected type \"Int\", found \"1\"."`

Is there any way to cast the userId argument passed in the URL to an integer?  Or is there a custom GraphQL scalar type that supports well-formed numeric strings as well as integers?  Any input or direction on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same problem recently and ended up with this solution:

```
<Route
            path="/user/:userId"
            component={User}
            queries={StoreQueries}
            prepareParams={({userId}) => ({userId: parseInt(userId, 10)})}/>
        />
```

Comment: That's what I wound up doing. Is this still the best solution in v4? Kinda sucks…